# Aligning verses differently

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verse

Is there a way to create the following layout using the verse package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{\nopagebreak\noindent
  \makebox[\dimexpr(\versewidth)+2em][r]{\footnotesize#1\hspace{-2em}}}

\begin{document}

\settowidth\versewidth{What if tomorrow the war could be over?}

\begin{flushright}
\parbox{\versewidth}{
This is a war and we are soldiers. \\
What if tomorrow the war could be over? \\
Isn't that worth fighting for? \\
Isn't that worth dying for? \\
\attrib{Morpheus}
}
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushleft}
\parbox{\versewidth}{
This is a war and we are soldiers. \\
What if tomorrow the war could be over? \\
Isn't that worth fighting for? \\
Isn't that worth dying for? \\
\attrib{Morpheus}
}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Is this possible to do it without using the \makebox for positioning the author (\attrib) ?

I'm just a beginner in both typography and LaTeX. I have experience only in website development.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Please check your code snippet -- it doesn't compile even when one adds `\documentclass{article}`.

Comment: I modified my previous code to fix the missing \usepackage{verse} and reflect my expected result better

Answer (score 2):

You should use the widest verse as the argument of `\settowidth\versewidth`; here's my proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{\nopagebreak\noindent
  \makebox[\dimexpr(\textwidth+\versewidth)/2][r]{\footnotesize#1\hspace{-2em}}}

\begin{document}

\settowidth\versewidth{What if tomorrow the war could be over?}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
This is a war and we are soldiers. \\
What if tomorrow the war could be over? \\
Isn't that worth fighting for? \\
Isn't that worth dying for? \\
\end{verse}

\attrib{Morpheus}

\end{document}
```

You can control the "outdent" of the attribution by acting on the spacing in the definition.

[image]

Comment: Nice, but I cannot flush the poem to the left or right

Comment: Ok, with some modifications it nearly does what I wanted... But now I have to use \parbox, and I cannot use \verse inside it. And I don't see the single point that is responsible for the width of the whole box (max_verse_line_width + xem). And what is that \makebox just to indent the \attrib?

Comment: Now I don't believe that this could be solved only with absolute positioning of a smaller box (\makebox) inside the bigger box (\parbox). In html it is considered as a hackish solution :-) Is that the ordinary solution in LaTeX?

Comment: Sorry, but it's you that want to use the `verse` package without looking at its documentation. You're free not to believing into something; I surely have helped as much as I could.

Comment: If you really want me to read the documentation, this leads back to: `\begin{flushright}\settowidth\versewidth{What if tomorrow the war could be over?}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
This is a war and we are soldiers. \What if tomorrow the war could be over? \Isn't that worth fighting for? \Isn't that worth dying for? \\attrib{Morpheus}
\end{verse}
\end{flushright}` which is not a working solution. Or what do you mean? If you are aware of a part which addresses my problems (positioning both the verse and the author) please tell me, which part of the documentation you are pointing to.