# different text alignment on even/odd pages (like raggedouter but for text)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page-breaking, automation, verse, poetry

For a poetry book I would like to typeset all text on even pages `\raggedleft` and all text on odd pages `\raggedright`, including headings. Poems can span across multiple pages, so the change of text alignment should happen automatically at page breaks. Ideally this would work also with the `verse` package.

The intended result would be something like this:
[image: intended result text alignment on even/odd pages]

Here's the spaghetti code for the example above:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=11cm,paperheight=14cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{verse}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em} % no indentation for verses

\begin{document}
\strut
\clearpage

\raggedleft\textbf{A Limerick}
\begin{verse}
\raggedleft
  There was an old party of Lyme \\
  Who married three wives at one time. \\
  When asked: ‘Why the third?’ \hspace{1em}\strut \\
  He replied: ‘One’s absurd, \hspace{1em}\strut \\
  And bigamy, sir, is a crime.’
\end{verse}

\clearpage

\raggedright\textbf{Love's lost}
\begin{verse}
  I used to love my garden \\
  \hspace{1em} But now my love is dead \\
  For I found a bachelor’s button \\
  \hspace{1em} In black-eyed Susan’s bed.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

I had a look at the following questions/answers but couldn't figure out how to solve my problem:

- [Different \marginparsep for odd and even pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27518/different-marginparsep-for-odd-and-even-pages)
- [different type areas on even/odd pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99103/different-type-areas-on-even-odd-pages)
- [\raggedouter to typeset marginal text in twoside book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32173/raggedouter-to-typeset-marginal-text-in-twoside-book)
- [Aligning verses differently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99092/aligning-verses-differently)

Maybe there is a low-level hack to switch the orientation of everything according to even/odd pages?

Comment: That does not seem to be easy: the `\raggedleft`/`\raggedright` setting is relevant in the phase in which TeX is breaking a paragraph into lines; if one paragraph is split across two pages, you cannot automatically have the first half (on the first page) typeset `\raggedleft` and the second half typeset `\raggedright`.  You need to interrupt the paragraph at the right spot, which is difficult to automate.

Comment: Addendum: the trick explained in _The TeXbook_, Appendix D, section 7 is not applicable here, because we do not know at which point in the paragraph the switch between ragged right and ragged left setting should occur—or do we?

Comment: We knew if we counted the number of lines we have on the respective page, this will be constant throughout the book. Unfortunately the trick in _The TeXbook_ is beyond my (La)TeX-skills.

Comment: I was reflecting that perhaps you do *not* need to have ragged left and ragged right margins in the same paragraph: usually, when typesetting a poem, each stanza makes a paragraph by itself.  Now, is it possible to introduce the constraint that each stanza must be confined to a single page?  That is, that a page break *cannot* occur between two lines of the same stanza?

Comment: For most poems this constraint would be acceptable. But in this book there are a few with very long stanzas that do not fit on one page, so there will be a page break somewhere.